# How to correct for Image Padding cannot be used error on Mathematica?

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica, padding, label

I am trying to plot the following in Mathematica 11:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
fN = n * r0^beta);

Plot[fN /. {r0 -> 0.5, beta -> 4}, {n, 0, 12}, PlotRange -> {{0, 12}, {0, 5}}, PlotLabels -> {"r0 = 0.5"}]
```

When I try to plot it without the `PlotLabels` it works well. However, when I try and plot it with the `PlotLabels`, I get the following error.

> The specified setting for the option GraphicsBoxOptions, ImagePadding
>   cannot be used.

Any ways to correct this?

Comment: That error makes me think possibly your file is corrupted. Suggest you start with a fresh notebook and retype that. If the problem persists try asking on mathematica.stackexchange.com  ( `PlotLabels` is a fairly new option, be sure to report your system/version in case this might be a bug )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works ok for me... don't know your problem

```
Clear["Global`*"]
fN = n*r0^beta;

Plot[{fN /. {r0 -> 0.5, beta -> 2}, fN /. {r0 -> 2.5, beta -> 1}, 
  fN /. {r0 -> 1.5, beta -> 3}}, {n, 0, 12}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 12}, {0, 5}}, 
 PlotLabels -> {"r0 = 0.5", "r0 = 2.5", "r0 = 1.5"}]
```